# homals package for Nonlinear PCA in R: Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, pca, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to implement NLPCA (Nonlinear PCA) on a data set using the `homals` package in `R` but I keep on getting the following error message:

`Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`

The data set I use can be found in the UCI ML Repository and it's called `dat` when imported in `R`: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/South+German+Credit+%28UPDATE%29

Here is my code (some code is provided once the data set is downloaded):

```
nlpcasouthgerman <- homals(dat, rank=1, level=c('nominal','numerical',rep('nominal',2),
                                                'numerical','nominal',
                                                rep('ordinal',2), rep('nominal',2),
                                                'ordinal','nominal','numerical',
                                                rep('nominal',2), 'ordinal',
                                                'nominal','ordinal',rep('nominal',3)),
                           active=c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, 20)), ndim=3, verbose=1)
```

I am trying to predict the first attribute, therefore I set it to be `active=FALSE`.
The output looks like this (skipped all iteration messages):

```
Iteration:   1 Loss Value:  0.000047 
Iteration:   2 Loss Value:  0.000044 
...
Iteration:  37 Loss Value:  0.000043 
Iteration:  38 Loss Value:  0.000043 
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I don't understand why this error comes up. I have used the same code on some other data set and it worked fine so I don't see why this error persists. Any suggestions about what might be going wrong and how I could fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error comes from code generating NAs in the `homals` function, specifically for your data for the `number_credits` levels, which causes problems with `sort(as.numeric((rownames(clist[[i]]))))` and the attempt to catch the error, since one of the levels does not give an NA value.

So either you have to modify the `homals` function to take care of such an edge case, or change problematic factor levels. This might be something to file as a bug report to the package maintainer.

As a work-around in your case you could do something like:

```r
levels(dat$number_credits)[1] <- "_1"
```

and the function should run without problems.

**Edit:**

I think one solution would be to change one line of code in the `homals` function, but no guarantee this does work as intended. Better submit a bug report to the package author/maintainer - see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/homals/ for the address.

Using `rnames <- as.numeric(rownames(clist[[i]]))[order(as.numeric(rownames(clist[[i]])))]` instead of `rnames <- sort(as.numeric((rownames(clist[[i]]))))` would allow the following code to identify NAs, but I am not sure why the author did not try to preserve factor levels outright.
Anyway, you could run a modified function in your local environment, which would require to explicitly call internal (not exported) `homals` functions, as shown below. Not necessarily the best approach, but would help you out in a pinch.

```r
homals <- function (data, ndim = 2, rank = ndim, level = "nominal", sets = 0, 
    active = TRUE, eps = 0.000001, itermax = 1000, verbose = 0) {
    dframe <- data
    name <- deparse(substitute(dframe))
    nobj <- nrow(dframe)
    nvar <- ncol(dframe)
    vname <- names(dframe)
    rname <- rownames(dframe)
    for (j in 1:nvar) {
        dframe[, j] <- as.factor(dframe[, j])
        levfreq <- table(dframe[, j])
        if (any(levfreq == 0)) {
            newlev <- levels(dframe[, j])[-which(levfreq == 0)]
        }
        else {
            newlev <- levels(dframe[, j])
        }
        dframe[, j] <- factor(dframe[, j], levels = sort(newlev))
    }
    varcheck <- apply(dframe, 2, function(tl) length(table(tl)))
    if (any(varcheck == 1)) 
        stop("Variable with only 1 value detected! Can't proceed with estimation!")
    active <- homals:::checkPars(active, nvar)
    rank <- homals:::checkPars(rank, nvar)
    level <- homals:::checkPars(level, nvar)
    if (length(sets) == 1) 
        sets <- lapply(1:nvar, "c")
    if (!all(sort(unlist(sets)) == (1:nvar))) {
        print(cat("sets union", sort(unlist(sets)), "\n"))
        stop("inappropriate set structure !")
    }
    nset <- length(sets)
    mis <- rep(0, nobj)
    for (l in 1:nset) {
        lset <- sets[[l]]
        if (all(!active[lset])) 
            (next)()
        jset <- lset[which(active[lset])]
        for (i in 1:nobj) {
            if (any(is.na(dframe[i, jset]))) 
                dframe[i, jset] <- NA
            else mis[i] <- mis[i] + 1
        }
    }
    for (j in 1:nvar) {
        k <- length(levels(dframe[, j]))
        if (rank[j] > min(ndim, k - 1)) 
            rank[j] <- min(ndim, k - 1)
    }
    x <- cbind(homals:::orthogonalPolynomials(mis, 1:nobj, ndim))
    x <- homals:::normX(homals:::centerX(x, mis), mis)$q
    y <- lapply(1:nvar, function(j) homals:::computeY(dframe[, j], x))
    sold <- homals:::totalLoss(dframe, x, y, active, rank, level, sets)
    iter <- pops <- 0
    repeat {
        iter <- iter + 1
        y <- homals:::updateY(dframe, x, y, active, rank, level, sets, 
            verbose = verbose)
        smid <- homals:::totalLoss(dframe, x, y, active, rank, level, 
            sets)/(nobj * nvar * ndim)
        ssum <- homals:::totalSum(dframe, x, y, active, rank, level, sets)
        qv <- homals:::normX(homals:::centerX((1/mis) * ssum, mis), mis)
        z <- qv$q
        snew <- homals:::totalLoss(dframe, z, y, active, rank, level, 
            sets)/(nobj * nvar * ndim)
        if (verbose > 0) 
            cat("Iteration:", formatC(iter, digits = 3, width = 3), 
                "Loss Value: ", formatC(c(smid), digits = 6, 
                  width = 6, format = "f"), "\n")
        r <- abs(qv$r)/2
        ops <- sum(r)
        aps <- sum(La.svd(crossprod(x, mis * z), 0, 0)$d)/ndim
        if (iter == itermax) {
            stop("maximum number of iterations reached")
        }
        if (smid > sold) {
            warning(cat("Loss function increases in iteration ", 
                iter, "\n"))
        }
        if ((ops - pops) < eps) 
            break
        else {
            x <- z
            pops <- ops
            sold <- smid
        }
    }
    ylist <- alist <- clist <- ulist <- NULL
    for (j in 1:nvar) {
        gg <- dframe[, j]
        c <- homals:::computeY(gg, z)
        d <- as.vector(table(gg))
        lst <- homals:::restrictY(d, c, rank[j], level[j])
        y <- lst$y
        a <- lst$a
        u <- lst$z
        ylist <- c(ylist, list(y))
        alist <- c(alist, list(a))
        clist <- c(clist, list(c))
        ulist <- c(ulist, list(u))
    }
    dimlab <- paste("D", 1:ndim, sep = "")
    for (i in 1:nvar) {
        if (ndim == 1) {
            ylist[[i]] <- cbind(ylist[[i]])
            ulist[[i]] <- cbind(ulist[[i]])
            clist[[i]] <- cbind(clist[[i]])
        }
        options(warn = -1)
# Here is the line that I changed in the code:
        # rnames <- sort(as.numeric((rownames(clist[[i]]))))
        rnames <- as.numeric(rownames(clist[[i]]))[order(as.numeric(rownames(clist[[i]])))]
        options(warn = 0)
        if ((any(is.na(rnames))) || (length(rnames) == 0)) 
            rnames <- rownames(clist[[i]])
        if (!is.matrix(ulist[[i]])) 
            ulist[[i]] <- as.matrix(ulist[[i]])
        rownames(ylist[[i]]) <- rownames(ulist[[i]]) <- rownames(clist[[i]]) <- rnames
        rownames(alist[[i]]) <- paste(1:dim(alist[[i]])[1])
        colnames(clist[[i]]) <- colnames(ylist[[i]]) <- colnames(alist[[i]]) <- dimlab
        colnames(ulist[[i]]) <- paste(1:dim(as.matrix(ulist[[i]]))[2])
    }
    names(ylist) <- names(ulist) <- names(clist) <- names(alist) <- colnames(dframe)
    rownames(z) <- rownames(dframe)
    colnames(z) <- dimlab
    dummymat <- as.matrix(homals:::expandFrame(dframe, zero = FALSE, clean = FALSE))
    dummymat01 <- dummymat
    dummymat[dummymat == 2] <- NA
    dummymat[dummymat == 0] <- Inf
    scoremat <- array(NA, dim = c(dim(dframe), ndim), dimnames = list(rownames(dframe), 
        colnames(dframe), paste("dim", 1:ndim, sep = "")))
    for (i in 1:ndim) {
        catscores.d1 <- do.call(rbind, ylist)[, i]
        dummy.scores <- t(t(dummymat) * catscores.d1)
        freqlist <- apply(dframe, 2, function(dtab) as.list(table(dtab)))
        cat.ind <- sequence(sapply(freqlist, length))
        scoremat[, , i] <- t(apply(dummy.scores, 1, function(ds) {
            ind.infel <- which(ds == Inf)
            ind.minfel <- which(ds == -Inf)
            ind.nan <- which(is.nan(ds))
            ind.nael <- which((is.na(ds) + (cat.ind != 1)) == 
                2)
            ds[-c(ind.infel, ind.minfel, ind.nael, ind.nan)]
        }))
    }
    disc.mat <- apply(scoremat, 3, function(xx) {
        apply(xx, 2, function(cols) {
            (sum(cols^2, na.rm = TRUE))/nobj
        })
    })
    result <- list(datname = name, catscores = ylist, scoremat = scoremat, 
        objscores = z, cat.centroids = clist, ind.mat = dummymat01, 
        loadings = alist, low.rank = ulist, discrim = disc.mat, 
        ndim = ndim, niter = iter, level = level, eigenvalues = r, 
        loss = smid, rank.vec = rank, active = active, dframe = dframe, 
        call = match.call())
    class(result) <- "homals"
    result
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just as a reference, because I will be using the ```homals``` function quite a lot, how can I spot what the problematic factor levels are and for which of my variables? Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: See my edit for a possible workaround solution, but better submit a bug report to the package maintainer/author. To answer your question, I believe the problematic cases would be those where `as.numeric((rownames(clist[[i]])))` has at least one non-NA and at least one NA element, since the `sort` command will silently suppress the NA cases, leading to the error.

Comment: Thank you very much - I will definitely report the bug to the package maintainer. In the meantime, I tried to run your solution on the original data and it worked, giving almost identical results (the differences of the object scores or the eigenvalues were infinitesimal) so it seems to be fine. Your observation is indeed right by the way; I tried to convert all nominal variables to get either words as levels or just integers and everything worked fine so probably the issue has to do with categorical levels including numerical and non-numeric labels.